# Implement Passport Local Strategy in hyperledger composer

Tags: angular, hyperledger-composer

Being a newbie in nodejs. I am building a hyperledger composer multi user application.
Following [this](https://medium.com/@CazChurchUk/developing-multi-user-application-using-the-hyperledger-composer-rest-server-b3b88e857ccc) tutorial.

I have also changed the COMPOSER_PROVIDERS variable, but still nothing works.
I have no clue how to implement the passport-local strategy in my angular app.

Comment: Please provide more details about what you tried, add code examples, etc, [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46216970/how-to-use-passport-local-to-authenticate-in-composer-rest-server I've tried this. But no outcome

Answer (score 0):

The Tutorial you point to uses 2 REST servers one of which is using `passport-github` for multi-user authentication.

There is a [worked example](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server) in the Composer documentation for the passport-github authentication, and a [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/tutorials/google_oauth2_rest) for `passport-google-oauth2`.

I would suggest working through one of those for some understanding before moving on to a passport-local scenario.

There is some additional information in another [Stack Overflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31594949/where-to-put-passportjs-local-strategy-in-an-express-application) that may help you further.